# How do I find the difference between columns, but only for the next non-zero value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame containing several million rows, each of which is similar to the following:

[image: Initial DataFrame]

```
2017-06-13         NaT         NaT         NaT         NaT         NaT         NaT  2017-10-28
2017-10-02         NaT         NaT         NaT         NaT         NaT         NaT  2017-10-28
2017-10-30  2017-10-31         NaT  2017-10-31  2017-11-01  2017-11-02  2017-11-03  2017-11-03
2017-10-30  2017-10-30         NaT  2017-10-30         NaT  2017-10-30  2017-11-01  2017-11-01
2017-10-02         NaT         NaT         NaT         NaT         NaT         NaT  2017-10-28
```

Each column is a step in a process and I am trying to find the time it takes to go from step to step. NaT values mean the step was skipped, so I would like to skip it in the calculations and count the time on the next (non-NaT) step.

In this example, for the first and second rows, I am looking for the difference between the last column and the first column. For third row, I am looking for the difference between the first and second columns, the fourth and second columns, the fifth and fourth columns etc. The expected output is similar to the following (if we are using days):

```
NaT   0     0     0     0     0     0   137
NaT   0     0     0     0     0     0   111
NaT   1     0     0     1     1     1     0
NaT   0     0     0     0     0     2     0
NaT   0     0     0     0     0     0    26
```

I am sure there is a way to do it with a for loop and if statements and subtracting the dates, but I was hoping for a more vectorized approach as the DataFrame is rather large.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your data but actual copy-able data such as you did with your expected output. It is hard to recreate your problem and find a solution this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I took the liberty to create a working example. Please do not share pictures of your data as recreating a MRE (minimal reproducable example) is expected and helps answering your question more quickly.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, datetime

dic = {
    "col1": [datetime(2020, 1, 1), datetime(2020,2,1), datetime(2020,3,1), datetime(2020,4,1)],
    "col2": [datetime(2020, 1, 4), np.nan, datetime(2020,3,5), datetime(2020,4,2)],
    "col3": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, datetime(2020,4,4)],
    "col4": [datetime(2020, 1, 6), datetime(2020,2,10), datetime(2020,3,6), datetime(2020,4,5)],
}

df.ffill(axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df - df.shift(axis=1)
df
```

This results in:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
0   NaT 3 days  0 days  2 days
1   NaT 0 days  0 days  9 days
2   NaT 4 days  0 days  1 days
3   NaT 1 days  2 days  1 days
```

Explanation: the `ffill(axis=1)`makes sure that every row with NaN (or NaT) is filled with the previous valid value. Then we substract a shifted dataframe from the orginal to calculate the days in between.